# PostSharp 5.1.9 Error connecting to the pipe server

Tags: c#, postsharp

I just installed PostSharp Version **5.1.9-preview**, because I hit a bug that PostSharp will not fix in their stable 5.0 version, but is assumed fixed in 5.1.1-alpha (the whole 5.1 line is recommended for .NET Core 2.0, but not deemed production ready yet, so it's either titled alpha or preview).

With 5.1.9-preview, NuGet packages updated to the same version without problems, my build fails, not with the project that encountered the bug, but right with the first project that is built. From the error messages, I assume their server (background/local on my machine) crashed during compilation:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: XXX.Core, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
>
> 1>C:\XXX\packages\PostSharp.5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): warning : Connection unexpectedly closed by the server.
>
> 1>C:\XXX\packages\PostSharp.5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): warning : Retrying to execute the pipe server.
>
> 1>C:\XXX\packages\PostSharp.5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): warning : Connection unexpectedly closed by the server.
>
> 1>C:\XXX\packages\PostSharp.5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): warning : Retrying to execute the pipe server.
>
> 1>C:\XXX\packages\PostSharp.5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): warning : Connection unexpectedly closed by the server.
>
> **1>C:\XXX\packages\PostSharp.5.1.9-preview\build\PostSharp.targets(340,5): error : Error connecting to the pipe server. See previous warnings for details.**

When I go into the project options and set the PostSharp "Build Host" setting from "Default(Server)" to "Native", as recommended by their support to see the actual errors of the server, it builds fine and without errors.

What I tried:

- Restart VS
- Reboot my machine
- Set "Build Host" to "Native" and back to "Default(Server)"
- Compiled a project in the same solution that has no dependencies, uses PostSharp but has not Aspects: This gets the usual "No Aspects, you can disable PostSharp" warning and works
- Installed 5.1.9-preview (breaks)
- Installed 5.1.6-alpha (breaks)
- Installed 5.1.4-alpha (breaks)
- Installed 5.1.3-alpha (works)
- Installed 5.1.2-alpha (works)
- Installed 5.1.1-alpha (works)

Apart from a bug they had way back with version 3.something, I could not find anything related in my search.

Any ideas how to solve this or how to find out what's wrong?

Comment: @mjwills Good question... I'll try an older 5.1 version.

Comment: @mjwills 5.1.1 works... I'll try to get more recent and see where it breaks...

Comment: 5.1.6 was still titled "alpha", 5.1.7 onwards was titled "preview". Trying 5.1.6, that already breaks. Trying something in the middle now.

Comment: But why not ask them via issue tracker \ forum? I mean it's unlikely people on SO can help with a bug in preview version of PostSharp better than PostSharp employees.

Comment: @Evk  Because they send you here if you use their free version... and I thought with a version several months old, I might not be the first one to stumble upon this. But you are right...

Comment: @Evk Matter of fact they are not open to reports from users that use the "Essentials" version. If you don't pay yearly, you better not have problems with their product :(

Comment: Bug being in preview version also doesn't help. Even if you paid - preview is preview, so not much obligations. And why not use 5.1.3-alpha in which your list above shows it works?

Comment: @Evk Forget what I said... their site is just so crappy that it crashes if you are not logged in. Without any explanation. So yeah, will try.

Comment: Whatever the problem was, it is fixed in version 6.0

Comment: I just found this question by chance. FYI: To ensure that a question about PostSharp or Metalama takes PostSharp employees' attention, mark such a question with a PostSharp or Metalama tag.

Comment: @AntonínProcházka Not sure what you are getting at? I posted this 6 years ago and I did tag it "postsharp" as you said, six years ago already.